# Android 13 deeplinking assetlink file

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-deep-link

I have configured dynamic deeplinking on firebase with the url prefix of xxx.page.link. Now I am having trouble figuring out where I should host the assetlink file. The deeplinks are working on android 12 and below.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the association between your website and your intent filters by hosting a Digital Asset Links JSON file at the following location:

```
https://domain.name/.well-known/assetlinks.json
```